# Fast way of getting all positions of the elements of a sub-list

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm trying to obtain all positions of a sub-list of elements taken from a big list.

In Python, using numpy, say I have

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, int64

n, N = 20, 120000
int_vocabulary = np.array(range(N))
np.random.shuffle(int_vocabulary)  # to make the problem non-trivial
int_sequence = np.random.choice(int_vocabulary, n, replace=False)
```

and I want to get all positions the integers taken in `int_sequence` have in the big sequence `int_vocabulary`. I'm interested in fast computation.

So far I've tried using numba brute force research, numpy mask approach, list comprehension brute force (for baseline), and list comprehension and numpy mask mixing.

```py
@jit(int64[:](int64[:], int64[:], int64, int64))
def check(int_sequence, int_vocabulary, n, N):
    all_indices = np.full(n, N)
    for xi in range(n):
        for i in range(N):
            if int_sequence[xi] == int_vocabulary[i]:
                all_indices[xi] = i
    return all_indices

t0 = dt.now()
for _ in range(10):
    all_indices0 = check(int_sequence, int_vocabulary, n, N)
t0 = (dt.now() - t0).total_seconds()
print("numba : ", t0)

t0 = dt.now()
for _ in range(10):
    mask = np.full(len(int_vocabulary), False)
    for x in int_sequence:
        mask += int_vocabulary == x
    all_indices1 = np.flatnonzero(mask)
t0 = (dt.now() - t0).total_seconds()
print("numpy :", t0)

t0 = dt.now()
for _ in range(10):
    all_indices2 = np.array([i for i, x in enumerate(int_vocabulary)
                             if x in int_sequence])
t0 = (dt.now() - t0).total_seconds()
print("list comprehension : ", t0)

t0 = dt.now()
for _ in range(10):
    mask = np.sum(np.array([int_vocabulary == x for x in int_sequence]), axis=0)
    all_indices3 = np.flatnonzero(mask)
t0 = (dt.now() - t0).total_seconds()
print("mixed numpy + list comprehension : ", t0)

assert np.sum(all_indices0) == np.sum(all_indices1)
assert np.sum(all_indices1) == np.sum(all_indices2)
assert np.sum(all_indices2) == np.sum(all_indices3)
```

each time I do the calculation 10 times to get comparable statistics. The outcome is

```bash
numba :  0.028039
numpy : 0.011616
list comprehension :  3.116753
mixed numpy + list comprehension :  0.032301
```

I nevertheless wonder whether there are faster algorithm for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about parallelism? This is easy to do with numba and your check function like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, int64, prange

n, N = 20, 120000
int_vocabulary = np.array(range(N))
np.random.shuffle(int_vocabulary)  # to make the problem non-trivial
int_sequence = np.random.choice(int_vocabulary, n, replace=False)

@jit(int64[:](int64[:], int64[:], int64, int64), parallel=True)
def check(int_sequence, int_vocabulary, n, N):
    all_indices = np.full(n, N)
    for xi in prange(n):
        for i in range(N):
            if int_sequence[xi] == int_vocabulary[i]:
                all_indices[xi] = i
    return all_indices

%%timeit
all_indices0 = check(int_sequence, int_vocabulary, n, N)
```

```
Out: 
     505 µs ± 32.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Comment: No, this is not a good idea here. The OP use a brute-force approach which is clearly inefficient. Using multiple threads just wast far more resources. This should be the last thing to do.

Comment: This is 5 time faster! Why not?

Comment: Because there are ways to make this (much) faster than 5 time without using more cores. Using more resources is not free. Here it typically consume more energy than optimizing the algorithm (which tends to be a problem in the current energy crisis for servers and not great for the battery of notebooks). Also note that the speed is dependent of the number of cores. Some machines still have only 2-4 cores (especially notebooks).